# Creating a Stored Procedure with Multiple Nested Begins

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can place multiple "Begins" in a procedure to drop and create tables?

My attempt -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procCreateCarTable
IS
    BEGIN

        BEGIN 
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE CARS';
        END;

        COMMIT;

        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE CARS (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(10), TITLE VARCHAR2(10))';
            COMMIT;
        END;
    END;
```

One by one the executes work but when creating this procedure I get the following error -

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Here is the SQL procedure that I got to work as mentioned in my comment below -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procCreateCarTable
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE CARS';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE CARS (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(10), TITLE  
  VARCHAR2(10))';
  COMMIT;  
END;
```

I added an EXCEPTION in case table CARS does not exist, but now my latest procedure below fails -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procCreateCarTable
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE CARS';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE CARS (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(10), TITLE      
  VARCHAR2(10))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TRUCKS';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TRUCKS (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(10), TITLE   
  VARCHAR2(10))';
  COMMIT;
END;
```

The only reason I could think of as to why my latest procedure failed is because of the other 'EXCEPTION'. I do want the other one there so the procedure can still create the TRUCKS table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you nesting BEGIN/END this way? Normally, one would only nest BEGIN/END for exception handling or variable scoping, and you aren't doing either here. Does your procedure compile in case you take all BEGIN/ENDs out except for the outer pair?

Comment: I want to have a procedure that drops and creates the table. If I remove the BEGINs and ENDs around those executions it throws a bunch of errors.

Comment: If you're getting errors without the additional BEGIN/ENDs then those are the ones that you need to deal with first: the additional BEGIN/ENDs aren't going to fix any problems here, only mask the underlying errors. Also, you don't need the COMMITs: all your statements are DDL and take effect immediately. When you try running the EXECUTE IMMEDIATEs are you using the same database user as you're using to compile the procedure?

Comment: I removed the nested BEGIN/END and placed only one COMMIT at the end of the process, right before END;. I kept the EXECUTES and it is working as expected now. Thanks for your help

Comment: To Kevin's point, though, adding and removing pairs of `BEGIN` and `END` statements and adding and removing `commit` statements will not create (nor resolve) any issues.  The code you posted originally appears to work just fine.  If removing the `BEGIN` and `END` statements fixed an issue, then the issue was somewhere other than the code you posted.

Comment: Also please note that commit has no effect on DDL statements. You can't 'rollback' a create statement that way.

Comment: Thanks. Stating COMMIT is what I would want if I did a DELETE in the procedure before executing another statement?

Answer (score 6):

Through trial and error I created the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procCreateCarTable
IS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE CARS';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE CARS (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(10), TITLE    
    VARCHAR2(10))';
  END;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TRUCKS';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TRUCKS (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(10), TITLE 
    VARCHAR2(10))';
  END;
END;
```